# Highcharts proper usage of datetime?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My current setup is somewhat static with xaxis categories and tickinterval(cant even see the graph without tickinterval).

If you change screen resolution it looks somewhat bad and I would like to have the x-axis to be dynamic.

What I've gathered you should use data like this http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/usdeur.js and xAxis like below?

```
xAxis: { type: 'datetime' }
```

But that example only uses YYMMDD, I also use hh:mm:ss.

Currently looks like this: i.imgur.com/v649otj.png

```
xAxis: {
        categories: getjson('Date'),
        tickInterval: 20
},
series: [
      {name:'Cars',       data: getjson('Values')},
]
```

Data:

```
getjson('Date') equals:
Array [ "2014-11-09 02:36:00", "2014-11-07 07:35:00", "2014-11-08 20:29:00", "2014-11-08 20:30:00", "2014-11-10 11:06:00", "2014-11-08 08:12:00", "2014-11-08 20:31:00", "2014-11-08 20:23:00", "2014-11-08 20:24:00", "2014-11-08 20:25:00", 190 till… ]


getjson('Values') equals:
Array [ 13, 209, 209, 19, 0, 209, 15, 13, 13, 19, 190 till… ]
```

So how do I make use of this data and the datetime configuration.
Somehow push the 'Date'-data into same array as 'values' and convert it into right date format?

Edit: Current work: http://jsfiddle.net/tws8x0pd/4/

Comment: Duplicate of [How to format datetime for (x,y) pair data for Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968970/how-to-format-datetime-for-x-y-pair-data-for-highcharts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Datetime` configuration uses `UTC` numbers not `YYMMDD`! You should pass your datetime data with `Date.UTC(year,month,day,hour,minute,second)` in Series `data` with the format:

```
series: [
  {name:'...', data: [ [ Date.UTC(year,month,day,hour,minute,second), value ],
                       [ Date.UTC(year,month,day,hour,minute,second), value ],
                       ...
                     ]
  }
]
```

so you should get the year,month,... out of your `json` date and put it with the corresponding value in `json` values. Each in one array, not apart in separate arrays.

Comment: Thanks!
I got this now: http://jsfiddle.net/tws8x0pd/2/
Which gives me: http://i.imgur.com/nVDGbX0.png

Displays xAxis how I want it except labels in a strange format.
How do I go on from this?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work. I'm not seeing anything, and it has lots of problems. Make it work and input some of your data in it, then I will see your problem

Comment: `d` should be `Date.UTC(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);`, not `new Date(Date.UTC(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]));`. And you should push `[d,parseInt(obj[x])]` not `[[d],parseInt(obj[x])]`. And at last your data should be sorted on `date` which is not. Sort `graphdata` on the first element and will be fine: http://jsfiddle.net/tws8x0pd/5/

Comment: Thank you so much! I even that the data wasn't sorted.

Answer (score 1):

The time require to be as timestamp (time in miliseconds) not strnig as you have. So you need to prepare correct data by Date.parse() / Date.UTC()